# How to fetch the data from form in angular 8

Tags: angular

```
 <form ngSubmit="loginUser()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
        <input matInput type="text" name="user_first_name" placeholder="First Name" value=" 
             {{data['user_first_name']}}">
        <button mat-button  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="First Name" (click)="firstname=''">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>                
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selected"  placeholder="Role">
          <mat-option value="User">User</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Viewer">Viewer</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>           
    </div>
```

I want to print the data entered inside text and dropdown in console I don't know how to capture this

Comment: When you want to print that data and why in console?

Comment: Try this approach. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-login-form-reactive-form).

Comment: Please read the documentation, and first decide whether you want to go template or reactive: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview ... or just use `[(ngModel)]` without form. I would suggest reactive :)

Comment: @ Binara Thambugala  not able to print anything in console

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables for your two fields and use [(ngModel)] in your form fields.

TS:

```
first_name: any;
role: any;
```

HTML:

```
<form ngSubmit="loginUser()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
        <input matInput type="text" name="user_first_name" placeholder="First Name" value=" 
             {{data['user_first_name']}}" [(ngModel)]="first_name" >
        <button mat-button  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="First Name" (click)="firstname=''">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>                
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Role" [(ngModel)]="role">
          <mat-option value="User">User</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Viewer">Viewer</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>           
    </div>
```

and on click of your button you can print those two values like this:

```
loginUser() {
    console.log(this.first_name);
    console.log(this.role);
}
```

Comment: actually I am using this form for update operation if I change only firstname and if I keep dropdown unchanged after submitting the form the dropdown value shows has "undefined" even through I have value in dropdown

Comment: it is not printing anything or I have to use any (click) in button

Comment: You have to assign the values to `first_name` and `role` then it will print. Like when you edit the fields that time assign `first_name=data['user_first_name']; role=selected`